# How to bubble events from MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

In this application I placed a Menu inside a Usercontrol.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="mainMenu">
            <MenuItem  Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open Analysis">
                    <MenuItem Header="Load all" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Select from tracks" />
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I would like to route and bubble all "click" events on the menu to a single Click event in the Usercontrol.
So I implemented:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent = eventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Click", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MenuItem));
public event RoutedEventHandler Click
{
    add { AddHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(ClickEvent, value); }
}
```

But that fails on the exception:

```
{"RoutedEvent Name 'Click' for OwnerType 'System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem' 
already used."}
```

I suppose this is the event is **registered multiple time's since there are multiple MenuItems**, so it fails the second time it wants to register.

But how can I "bundle" (like a Singular handler attachment point) all those events into one single event in the usercontrol in a good mainainanble way? Since some submenus are **fed by the Database thus are dynamically build-up.**

Comment: You can define one event for all the MenuItems, and in the event handler to check, what element caused the event, for example: `if (MenuItemSender.Header == "Load all") { LoadAll(); }`. Anyway, the practice of creating an event, in this case, would not be justified because already have for this event (`Click`, `MouseLeftButtonDown`).

Comment: I need a  Click event on the UserControl.

Comment: Sorry for the fact that finding fault, but the events must be for controls, such as buttons, menus, etc. `UserControl` it combines all these elements, it should not become attached to them, because today you need a menu item / button, then this in `UserControl` need to implement other elements that use other events. Especially, some (me too), prefer `DataTemplate`, that would be if instead of `UserControl` use the `DataTemplate`? It does not involve any events. It is desirable that `UserControl` does not depend on the elements that are in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to intuition, the error you are receiving is not due to multiple menu items, but due to the `Click` event already existing. The event registration is static, and it is already used by the WPF Framework.

How would you solve this?

You can create a style for your menu; styles can contain `EventSetters` in WPF. This allows you to register a click handler for any menu item in your container:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnMenuItemClick" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Menu x:Name="mainMenu">
           ...
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
```

Then in your handler make sure to set the `Handled` property to `true`, to stop bubbling:

```
 private void OnMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

**Update**
You should consider not firing the 'Click' event on the UserControl for this, since it could be a design issue: when someone uses your UserControl and the Click event is fired on the user control, you expect a 'Click', not a click on a menu item inside the control.

Consider using a custom event name instead, something like `MenuItemClick`, where you can supply the identifier of the menu item in the event args.

Comment: This does not expose the event outside the usercontrol. And works the same as the property MenuItem.Click="MenuItem_Click" in the menu control.

Comment: Bas: I Appreaciate your answer, however my question is How to bubble events from MenuItems, not how to fire them.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what's already been said, I would look into a simple messaging solution.

Each time you click on any menu item, you can broadcast a message of type `MenuItemClickedMessage`.

```
public class MenuItemClickedMessage
{
   public MenuItem MenuItemClicked { get; set; }
}
```

You can then have a single component that listens to that event. Once it receives the event, you can extract the menu item from `MenuItemClicked` property and react accordingly.

This will require some research into simple messaging solutions: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/

Answer (score 2):

Although I would strongly suggest not to do this, but instead declare a distinct new event as Bas has pointed out, you could simply reuse the existing RoutedEvent from class MenuItem:

```
public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click
    {
        add { AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is indeed correct as is being asked, but I would also advise against this. Try creating a Button in the user control and firing the click; it won't bubble up.

Answer (score 2):

MenuItemClick - is a routed event, and use RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource, rather than sender. This points to the control that originally fired the event.

```
<Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="mainMenu">
            <MenuItem  Header="File" Click="OnFileMenuItemClicked">
                <MenuItem Header="Open Analysis">
                    <MenuItem Header="Load all" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Select from tracks" />
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
</Grid>


private void OnFileMenuItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
    if(null != item)
    {
        // Handle the menuItem click here
    }
}
```